# $Scope.$Apply() returns a circular json error after loading data into an angular-ui-grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, angular-ui-grid

I have a snippet of js that causes an update in the webpage when $Scope.$apply is called.  Specifically, it causes the data in an angular-ui-grid to update.

An example:

The code is triggered by this HTML:

```
<div google-chart chart = "chartObject" style = "height:600px; width:100%;" agc-on-select="selectHandler(selectedItem)" ng-if="chartvisible"></div>
```

This Creates a UI grid:

```
$scope.gridOptions = gridService.getGrid([25, 50, 75], 25, ['username','startTime']);
 

    $scope.gridOptions.data = post;
     $scope.$apply();
```

Where the variable 'Post' is something like:

```
[
   {
       "challenge": "asdfrew2",
       "id": 1,
       "startTime": "start time 1",
       "successfullyCompleted": false,
       "username": "JamieFalter"
   },
   {
       "challenge": "454454y",
       "id": 2,
       "startTime": "start time 2",
       "successfullyCompleted": false,
       "username": "Falter"
   }
]
```

Returns an error that looks like this:

> TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
>
> ```
> at na (angular.js:1121)
> at angular.js:20566
> at Object.fn (angular.js:12411)
> at k.$digest (angular.js:12540)
> at k.$apply (angular.js:12805)
> at Object.<anonymous> (Controller.js:54)//Points to the Scope.Apply
> at i (jquery.min.js:2)
> at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
> at y (jquery.min.js:4)
> at XMLHttpRequest.c (jquery.min.js:4)
> ```

Has anyone seen anything like this before?  If so, how did you solve it?

Comment: why are using `$apply` if you are already in `angular context`?

Comment: @ram1993 I'm using $apply to force it to run a new $digest cycle.  Without it, the contents of the angular-ui-grid will not update.  If you have an alternate suggestion to do this, it would be appreciated.